# React native reset ScrollView height

Tags: react-native, scrollview

I am using ScrollView with tabs like this

```
<ScrollView ref={ref => this.scrollView = ref}>
<Tabs tabBarUnderlineStyle={style.tabUnderLine} onChangeTab={({ i }) => this.tabChange(i)}>

                                <Tab heading="Subscribing" textStyle={style.tabTextStyle} activeTextStyle={style.activeTextTab}>
                                    <FollowingPosts  ref={instance => { this.FollowingPostsChild = instance; }}  />
                                </Tab>
                                <Tab heading="Following" textStyle={style.tabTextStyle} activeTextStyle={style.activeTextTab}>
                                    <FollowingPosts  ref={instance => { this.FollowingPostsChild = instance; }}  />
                                </Tab>
                            </Tabs>
</ScrollView>
```

Now both tabs have same height 
so, I want to reset ScrollView height on tab change.

Comment: I have the same problem. are you fixed it?